# Get around ExtrinsicBaseWeight

Tags: extrinsic, frontier-node-template

I want to fix the Gas fee for every transaction ever i my *frontier-node-template*. I've implemented this for the substrate runtime

```rust
pub const FIXED_GAS_FEE: u32 = 2500;
pub struct ConstantFee<T>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
impl<T> WeightToFeePolynomial for ConstantFee<T>
where
    T: BaseArithmetic + From<u32> + Copy + Unsigned,
{
    type Balance = T;

    fn polynomial() -> WeightToFeeCoefficients<Self::Balance> {
        smallvec!(WeightToFeeCoefficient {
            coeff_integer: FIXED_GAS_FEE.into(),
            coeff_frac: Perbill::zero(),
            negative: false,
            degree: 0,
        })
    }

    fn calc(weight: &Weight) -> Self::Balance {
        FIXED_GAS_FEE.into()
    }
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const TransactionByteFee: Balance = 0;
}
impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, ()>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<0>;
    type WeightToFee = ConstantFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = ConstantMultiplier<Balance, TransactionByteFee>;
    type FeeMultiplierUpdate = ();
}
```

How ever, every transaction seems to cost 125,000,000 gas, which I located as the BaseExtrinsicWeight, and my ConstantFee struct seems to have no affect on the gas fee.

I would like to,

1. Ignore all weights
2. Set gas fee as a constant in the substrate runtime and for the EVM

how can I go by doing this?

---

**UPDATE**

I increased FIXED_GAS_FEE to 9 decimals, now it seems to work. It appears we have a minimum gas fee of 125_000_000, maybe I could only have gas in some particular order of decimals? Thoughts?

Comment: The configuration you are showing above is adjusting the fee of a transaction, but does not affect the Gas (or Weight) consumed by a transaction. It would be better for you to clarify what you are trying to achieve, since you seem to be confusing different things together.

Comment: We would like to fix the fee of the substrate and EVM transaction, and fix the Decimals the balances pallet considers our token to have.